# How to get username from Linux kernel space

Tags: linux, module, linux-kernel, system-calls

I am doing some Linux module development, restricting me to only kernel-available libraries, and I'd like to get the username of the user who is interacting with my module's username. AKA their "whoami". My module is actually wrapping around syscalls... I can get pid's from current->pid in kernel space. Is there any way to, perhaps, use the pid to track down the user to whom the pid belongs? Or another more simple way?

Thanks

Comment: There are fields in `task_struct` which hold owner information (UID, GID, effective UID, effective GID, etc.), but only as numeric IDs. All ID/name resolution services, provided by `libc`, are implemented in userspace in the so-called naming services switch (NSS). There are no kernel routines to do the resolution as far as I know since the kernel only works with IDs (similar to how it only works with numeric IP addresses)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [filp_open](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/open.c#L922) function to open `/etc/passwd` file from the kernel. Next you'll need to use the [file_operations](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/fs.h#L1777) to read the file:

```
struct file * file = filp_open(...);
file->f_op->read(file, ...);
```

Reading the file contents may be helpful for `UID -> username` translation.

Comment: This only works if usernames are mapped in `/etc/passwd`. But maps can also come from NIS, NIS+, LDAP, etc.

Comment: @HristoIliev: Sure. No way in that case. Netlink + uid2name daemon as a possible solution.

Comment: I use your method, but I can only read part of the passwd file into the buffer

Comment: @Jianchen No telepathic peoples here